# box resize in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

when i resize the box it not change the property of span.. . . .. . .. . . . . . . . . . . .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").resize(function(){
        if ($(".box").width() < 60) {
     $(".s").css("color","red");   
   }
  else {
      $(".s").css("color","blue");
   }
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: red;
  }
  .box:hover{
   width: 120px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
 </div>
 <br/>
 <span class="s">hello word</span>
```

Comment: You never go to your `$(".box").resize` part, read this : https://api.jquery.com/resize/. `resize` works on `window` only

Comment: You can change the color with CSS like you did with the width. I do not get why you need jQuery for this...

Comment: It a demo of what i want.....

Comment: you can done that in css part only

Answer (score 0):

`$('.box').resize` not going to work. Use window resize instead.

Below code, you can use

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(".box").width() < 60) {
     $(".s").css("color", "red");
   } else {
     $(".s").css("color", "blue");
   }
 });
```

If you want to change the span color on box hover changes the css as below

```
.box:hover span {  color: blue; }
```

Comment: i not want to use window ...so what i use to make this .